# Make Tmap keep the same viewport when redrawing (R/Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, gis, tmap

I'd like to store the centre coordinates and zoom in Tmap so that when the map gets redrawn it uses the last known centre point and zoom level.  The current behaviour is that it resets to the initial centre point and zoom level as per repro:

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)

data(World)
world_vars <- setdiff(names(World), c("iso_a3", "name", "sovereignt", "geometry"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  tmapOutput("map"),
  actionButton("randVar", "Random")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  map.center = c(lon=-2.460938,lat=54.444492)     # The center of the viewport
  map.zoom = 4                                    # The current zoom level

  rv <- reactiveValues(var = 1)
  
  output$map <- renderTmap({
    tmap_mode("view")
    tm_shape(World) +
      tm_polygons(world_vars[rv$var]) + 
      tm_view(set.view = c(map.center['lon'], map.center['lat'], zoom=map.zoom))
  })
  
  ## ---------------
  observeEvent(input$map_bounds, {
    map.zoom <- input$map_zoom
    map.center['lon'] <- input$map_center[['lng']]
    map.center['lat'] <- input$map_center[['lat']] 
    print(map.center)
    print(map.zoom)
  })    
  
  ## ---------------
  observeEvent(input$randVar, {
    rv$var <- sample(1:length(world_vars), 1)
  })    
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Zoom or pan the map and then press 'Random'.

The expected behaviour is for the map to redraw and for set.view to use the last centre point and zoom, but it resets to its initial setting?

Comment: SOLVED (day 2).  Every day is a school day with R/Shiny.  The answer is to assign global variables with <<- not = or <-.  Working code posted below

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)

data(World)
world_vars <- setdiff(names(World), c("iso_a3", "name", "sovereignt", "geometry"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  tmapOutput("map"),
  actionButton("randVar", "Random")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  map.center <<- c(lon=-2.460938,lat=54.444492)     # The center of the viewport
  map.zoom <<- 4                                    # The current zoom level
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(var = 1)
  
  output$map <- renderTmap({
    tmap_mode("view")
    tm_shape(World) +
      tm_polygons(world_vars[rv$var]) + 
      tm_view(set.view = c(map.center['lon'], map.center['lat'], zoom=map.zoom))
  })
  
  ## ---------------
  observeEvent(input$map_bounds, {
    map.zoom <<- input$map_zoom
    map.center['lon'] <<- input$map_center[['lng']]
    map.center['lat'] <<- input$map_center[['lat']] 
    print(map.center)
    print(map.zoom)
  })    
  
  ## ---------------
  observeEvent(input$randVar, {
    rv$var <- sample(1:length(world_vars), 1)
  })    
}   

shinyApp(ui, server)
```